# ansible link from directory to directory

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that creates a directory, creates content on index.html, and a link from /web_hosting to  /var/www/html.

The directory is called /web_hosting
the content is /web_hosting/index.html
I do not want to change the httpd.conf default web directory to /web_hosting I just want to use a link.

After running the play when I curl the server I'm not seeing the content from the index.html file. 
Can someone help me with my play?

---

- name: setup webserver and link to folder
  hosts: prod
  tasks:

  - name: create dir
    file:
    path: /web_hosting
    state: directory
    setype: httpd_sys_content_t
    mode: 0775
  - name: install
    yum:
    name: httpd
    state: present
  - name: configure service
    service:
    name: httpd
    state: started
    enabled: true
  - name: create content on index.html
    copy:
    dest: /web_hosting/index.html
    content: "hello from {{ansible_hostname}}"
  - name: create link
    file:
    src: /web_hosting
    dest: /var/www/html
    state: link

Comment: This has nothing to do with ansible but with your apache configuration: https://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like an Ansible problem if it is creating the files and not erroring out.

If you manually create a file in /var/www/html/ called "index2.html", can you use curl to see it?  If not, then it's definitely NOT an Ansible problem.

If that test works, then look for differences in ownership, SELinux permissions, etc.  Then use Ansible to set those properly on your "index.html".

I suspect you might need to enable a "follow links" setting in your webserver configuration.  But again, that's not an Ansible issue either - though Ansible could update the configuration file once you figure out what setting(s) to apply.

Comment: I tried that and I can curl index2.html without any problems but not index.html which lives in /web_hosting/index.html.  I will check out all permissions and make them like for like and look into follow links.
Thanks for the tips!!

Comment: Hi I checked everything and it was not an ansible problem. I rebooted the server and it now works not sure why but I'm glad you reviewed my work and helped me!

Comment: Glad it helped - if it happens again, might try restarting the webserver service and/or ensuring that the firewall service has been restarted.  Since a "Magic Reboot" helped, those would be my first items to look into.